# How to Trigger custom Video player While playing any video in iphone?

Tags: ios, ios5, mpmovieplayer

I want to create a Custom Video Player with some more features and settings .

So My question is:

1) Can i trigger my app when user clicks any video ?
2)How can i get list of all videos saved in iPhone (not in camera roll) ?i want to play them inside the video player i created.

Please guide me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can capture all video. External Apps tend to use Apple's native video support.

The only exception to this is if you register your application to open certain filetypes. Then applications can allow you to open the file in an external app such as yours. But this will require the cooperation of the other apps to implement "Open In" functionality; Very few apps tend to offer this functionality due to native support of video. 
See here [Apple Documentation](http://bit.ly/y2qC00)

The filesystem is locked down, if it's not in the camera roll or "Open In" you can't access it.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for this  "Open In" functionality.